# What is the best way of duplicating around 1500 mysql entries in to the same table with a small change?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, duplicates

I have a number of entries in a database which are assigned to a specific account within my php application. I need to duplicate all of the entries with the account_id of 5 and give the duplicated entries an account_id of 6 so they can be edited independently by the 2 different accounts.

Normally I'd just grab all the entries with an account_id of 5 then loop through them using php inserting a new entry for each one but with 1500+ entries I imagine that's not the best idea!

Is there any way to do this with SQL?

Comment: Can you post the table structure?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, with a subselect of an insert statement.

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO table (account_id, column1, column2)
SELECT 6, column1, column2 FROM table WHERE account_id = 5;
```

You can find more info about this [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).